# How To Validate Bcrypt Passwords Which Have $2y$ prefix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, bcrypt

Lets say i have a set of passwords using `Bcrypt` with `$2y$` prefix.Now i am moving to elixir for my website.so i am using [Comeonin](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin#usage)  as password hashing library, when i check my old `passwords` using following function `Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("hard to guess", stored_hash)`, I am getting `Argument` error like   `Comeonin Bcrypt does not support the 2y prefix`, how can i validate use passwords?

Comment: Can you provide a password and it's `$2y$` hash for testing purposes?

Comment: @Sheharyar `Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("pass1234", "$2y$12$qGz.0gYxDW//STSqUxPmL.6.36MlZuJh.AuWGDT7Yo25rUbNN6Qui")`

Comment: Looked in to comeonin. It doesn't implement the `2x` and `2y` bcrypt prefixes, and there doesn't seem to be any other elixir library that does it either. If you really want to implement this in Elixir, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Just changing `2y` to `2a` seems to function correctly with Comeonin's Bcrypt for me. Could you confirm? `Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("pass1234", "$2a$12$qGz.0gYxDW//STSqUxPmL.6.36MlZuJh.AuWGDT7Yo25rUbNN6Qui")`.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an extra non-breaking space when I copy your code or even copy from my comment above. Please try copying from here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1e13b6b91cf95243a1a6c4cd2ab5e4c.

Comment: @Dogbert as u told changing `$2y$` to `$2a$` or `$2b$` working correctly, but is it secure and good approach?

Comment: @Dogbert i added the `code` in [](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a1e13b6b91cf95243a1a6c4cd2ab5e4c) please check

Answer (score 0):

`$2y$` is identical to *"real"* bcrypt hashes.

If your library doesn't understand `$2y$`, there's no harm in replacing:

```
hash = StringReplace(hash, '$2y$', '$2a$');
```

The `$2y$` prefix was created by one buggy bcrypt library somewhere. Turns out they were generating incorrect bcrypt hashes. And then in 2011 they decided to change their library so it outputs `$2y$` as a prefix rather than `$2a$`.

The versions `$2x`, `$2y$` are not *"newer"*, or *"better"*, or *"stronger"* than `$2a$` - they're all the same.